# Firebase: When Sign In failed, how to get the error code?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have coded a service use to sign-in users:

```
func login(email: String, password: String) -> Bool {

    var userIsConnected = false

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(type(of: error)) // Print 'NSError'
            print(error!)
        }

        else {

            userIsConnected = true
        }
    }
    return userIsConnected
}
```

When I `print` the `error` I get:

> Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain **Code=17008** "The email address is badly
>   formatted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The email address is
>   badly formatted., error_name=ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL}

How can I get the `Code` value (17008) to be able to do some custom behaviour ?

Note: In a previous version of `FirebaseAuth` we can simply do `error.code` but in the last version we can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of error is `Error` and `Error` can be casted to `NSError`.

```
if let error = error, (error as NSError).code == 17008 {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY `error?.localizedDescription`

```
    // to show error through alert controller
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "your title", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: AlertActionTitle, style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: OP is looking for the `code` and not the message associated with it.